# How to split EditText into 2 lines after exceeding 15 signs

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have a normal EditText and I want to make it two lines when user inputs more than 15 signs.
My solution now is EditText in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enter_text_field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="@string/create_title_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    />
```

And I have a listener for text change, which onTextChanged method looks like that:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(!s.toString().contains("\n") && s.toString().length() > 14)
            setText(s.toString()+"\n");

}
```

But it doesn't work. Actually what happens is cursor getting at the beginning of the line.
How to make it split after inputing more than 15 signs properly? Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: What does your `setText()` method does?

Comment: It's basically: `mEditText.setText(text);`

Comment: That will generate a stackOverflow Exception because it will loop. Every time you change the text, it enters the callback and adds a line, then reenters the callback and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a close approach to what you are looking for:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/linkEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/create_title_hint"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxLength="31"
        android:nextFocusDown="@null"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Then on code, I did:

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 15){
                mEditText.setText(s.toString()+"\n");
                mEditText.setSelection(s.length()+1);
            }

        }
```

This will make the `EditText` skip to next line once it has 15 characters and moves the cursor to the end of the text.